# Azure Logic App to dynamically get Blob contents from Azure blob container without having to save the name of the file in path

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'am using an Azure Logic app to get Blob contents from my Azure container. The Blobs are getting stored monthly in my container in the format :-
Eg. mycontainer/invoice/20200101/invoice1.csv, mycontainer/invoice/20200201/invoice2.csv, so on & so forth.
In other words, every month's invoice is getting stored in my container dynamically with a folder denoting the month and day as in the example. (2020-01-01, yyyyMMdd format)

So far, I'am able to pick up the latest folder created in my container. That is October in this case, since we're in Oct. But I wish to pick up the latest file present in that folder.

My current workflow is as follows:-

[image: Current Workflow]

Any advice regarding this ?
Thanks!

Comment: There is only one file in each folder ? Like `mycontainer/invoice/20200101/invoice1.csv`, `mycontainer/invoice/20200201/invoice2.csv` ? Or there are multiple files in each folder, like `mycontainer/invoice/20200101/invoice1.csv`, `mycontainer/invoice/20200101/invoice2.csv`, `mycontainer/invoice/20200101/invoice3.csv` ?

Comment: Exactly, only one file. But there's a unique name attached to the file name. 
Something like this -> mycontainer/invoice/20200101/BillingInvoice_c96d6c-497f-bb58-624237288cec.csv,
mycontainer/invoice/20200201/BillingInvoice_d5lhk6-cd6c-49769-bb58-92002288cec.csv, like so

Comment: Ok, I will test it in my side and then provide a solution below. But I want to know if the folder name `20200101` or `20200101-20200131`

Comment: Yes @Hury, the folder name will be 20200101-20200131, 20200201-20200228,........ 20201001-20201031, 20201101-20201130, etc. This will be the format for the folder name. Every month, first date to last date, (yyyyMMdd format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide entire logic app for your reference, most of actions are same as yours:

**1.** The overview of the logic app
[image]

**2.** The first three actions
[image]

**3.** Fourth and fifth action
[image]

**4.** Details of "**For each**" loop
[image]

The expression in "**Set variable**" is `int(substring(items('For_each')?['Name'], 0, 8))` and the expression in "**Set variable 3**" is `replace(items('For_each')?['Name'], '/', '')`

**5.** The last two actions
[image]

The last expression in "**Get blob content**" action is `body('List_blobs_2')?['value'][0]?['Name']`

====================================**Update**=================================

**1.** Delete the last action "**Get blob content**" of your logic app.

**2.** Then we start after the action "**List blobs 2**". Add two "**Initialize variable**".
[image]

**3.** Add another "**For each**" loop. **Please note**: choose `value` from "**List blobs 2**" into "**For each 2**" but not choose `value` from "**List blobs**" into "**For each 2**".
[image]

**4.** The details in the "**For each 2**" loop.
[image]

The expressions of both `fx ticks(...)` are `ticks(items('For_each_2')?['LastModified'])`

And in "**Set variable 5**", also choose the `Name` from "**List blobs 2**" but not from "**List blobs**".

**5.** Then add "**Get blob content**" action like below screenshot.
[image]

**6.** By the way: Please do this setting for all of the "**For each**" loop action in your logic app before you run the logic app. Otherwise, the result may be incorrect.

Click `...` button of the "For each" action and click "Settings", enable `Concurrency Control` and set `Degree of Parallelism` as `1`.
[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to achieve this with multiple files getting stored instead of just one?

Comment: @SD4 You mean multiple files in one folder(`20201101-20201130`) ?

Comment: @SD4 Wait a moment

Comment: Yes sure! 
Just wanted to clarify, multiple files getting stored in one folder. But need to get only the latest file which is added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223608/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-sd4).

Comment: Hi @SD4 Please refer to the "Update" of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an Event Grid trigger from your BLOB to Logic App. As soon as a new file is saved in the BLOB it can publish an event to Event Grid where your Logic App can subscribe to that event and then you can run your workflow. Rather than doing a loop this way you can trigger a logic app workflow every time a file is saved.

Learn more about Event Grid from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview).

Comment: Okay @Hassan, thanks for your reply. Will check this